# How to share a common variable values in multiple if statements of void OnMouseDown() function

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I hit a "Credits" button, scene number 6 is Loaded. When I hit a back button in scene 6, application should return to the scene previously loaded. For example, Currently I am in Scene 3. When I hit a credits button, current scene(in this case 3)  will be saved in variable currentLevel. When my application is in Scene 6 and back button is hit, it should return to 3. But instead it return to scene 0. I do not why it is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
    int currentLevel;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction);
        if (hit.collider != null) {

            if(hit.collider.name == "Credits")
            {   
                currentLevel = Application.loadedLevel;
                Debug.Log (currentLevel);
                Application.LoadLevel(6);
            }


            if(hit.collider.name == "BackButton") 
            {   Debug.Log ("Current level" + currentLevel);
                Application.LoadLevel(currentLevel);
            }


        }
}
```

Comment: Does this script have DontDestroyOnLoad on it? Is this script attached to multiple gameobjects?

Comment: No, this script does not have DontDestroyOnLoad. And yes, this script is attached to multiple objects.

Comment: That's the problem then. Each instance of your script has it's own version of currentLevel, all of which are being initialized with a value of 0. I'll post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a manager / singleton that maintains the state of the currentLevel field.

So, Create a new script and paste the below code into it.

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static LevelManager instance;
    public int currentLevel = 0;

    void Awake () {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Now, in your script, change your code to

```
LevelManager.instance.currentLevel = Application.loadedLevel;
```

while loading your new scene, and

```
Application.LoadLevel(LevelManager.instance.currentLevel);
```

while clicking on the back button.

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject) Which GameObject does not destroy on Load? What does it mean?

Comment: To which gameObject is this LevelManager script  attached?

Comment: Attach it to any GameObject. Ideally, just create an empty GameObject, and attach LevelManager to it

Comment: When I hit a credits button, this error shows up "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line  LevelManager.instance.currentLevel = Application.loadedLevel;